# Javascript events blocked by flashplayer

Tags: javascript, flash, strobe-media-playback

**Is there any strategy to have an event** (e.g. keyup) **in a flash player with focus** (user clicked into it / changed volume, whatever) **still triggered in javascript without having to go into actionscripting?**

I've got a popup that's 100% filled by a player. On first load, if i dont click in the player, the event handler works and clicking "f" moves the player a bit down and a menu (underlying div) appears, the user can chose another video there. But if the user clicks inside the player or changes volume, I feel i have no chance of getting hold of the "f"-click again.. I'm using the Strobemediaplayback.

One - stupid - thing I've tried is to use the blur-event, so that when body loses blur, it immediatly regains it. Works but results in the player freezing for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll-event does trigger, even if the player has focus.

```
$('#popupWrapper').scroll(function () {

    // I run whether or not the player has focus

});
```